# Problemas en php y mysql

Tags: php, base-de-datos, app

En una app que estoy haciendo y mando el usuario y contraseña por una *URL* para comprobar si existe el usuario en la base de datos, la *URL* responde bien, pero cuando le trato de leer una tercera columna con el **roll** no me deja y responde error.

Este es el php de conexión a los datos:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// 1.- IDENTIFICACION nombre de la base, del usuario, clave y servidor
$db_host="*****";
$db_name="*****"; 
$db_login="*****"; 
$db_pswd="********"; 

// 2.- CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS
$link = new mysqli($db_host, $db_login, $db_pswd, $db_name);

// 3.- COMPROBAR SI EXISTE ESA PAREJA DE NOMBRE - CLAVE -ROLL
$datos=$_GET;

$Nombre=$datos['Nombre'];
$Clave=$datos['Clave'];

////////////////////////////// CONSULTAR /////////////////////////////////////

$res=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT nombre,clave FROM `usuarios_datos` WHERE `nombre`='$Nombre' AND `clave`='$Clave' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if( $count >= 1 ) { // Si hay 1 o m?s Juan - 1234, es que el usuario y clave existen.
echo 'REGISTRADO';
} else {
echo 'NO EXISTE';
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: En tu código no veo nada relativo a la columna `rol`. Si te refieres a leerlo desde la base de datos, debes incluir esa columna en el `SELECT`.

Comment: Saludos. Coincido con @A.Cedano ; te falta agregar e indicar el código y error que se genera.

Answer (score 0):

buenas cuando añado el campo roll en el select el servidor registra el suiguiente error y por lo tanto no recibe toda la respiuesta... me explico:

```
*.*.*.* - - [Mon Jul 13 21:17:47 2020] "GET /app/usuarios_conecta.php?Nombre=miguel&Clave=123456&ROLL= HTTP/1.1" 200 29 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; WP6 Build/PPR1.180610.011)"
```

la aplicacion manda esta url a la base de datos si dentro esta miguel (usuario) y con la contraseña 123456 la aplicacion pasa a una segunda pantalla y esa persona esta logueada... pero despues de la contrasela esta el apartado ROLL que lo devuelve vacio, por qwue no lee la comuna roll....

no se si me he explicado bien

Comment: Esto adjuntalo en tu preguta. La seccion de respuestas, solo es usada para responder, no es una extension de tu pregunta.